# callというのはどういった関数でしょうか

Tags: javascript, node.js

callというのはどういった関数でしょうか？検索してみてもいきなり専門用語だらけで理解できませんでした。プログラムをよく知らない人に分かる感じでおおまかな内容を教えてください。お願いします。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score -3):

[JavaScript の call( ) メソッドを雑に説明](https://qiita.com/Chrowa3/items/b3e2961c4930abc1369b)　を読んでみてください。

Comment: [引用などでリンクの文脈（内容）を提示してください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)